# How to set a link's NavigateUrl on link onClick?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a link dynamically. The `NavigateUrl`property of the link is set on a call to a method. But I don't want to call the method before the link is clicked because there are so many of such links.

Any help on how to do it is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public void CreateLink()
{
   LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
   link.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);
   string key = GetKey();
}

private void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = GetLinkUrl(e.???);
    Response.Redirect(url);       
}


public string GetLinkUrl(string key)
{
    //do things to retrieve url
    return url;
}
```

Update: Many thanks, all :) I am going to use LinkButton, as seen in updated code above.
But I forgot to ask: There is a key associated with each link which is needed to get the URL. How can I

Comment: You might find that a LinkButton suits your purpose better.

Comment: How does your code know which key goes with which link? Or is it a global key? I would be putting the key in an attribute on the link itself, then reading that attribute in the handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to use an ASP button instead of Hyperlink, and bind the `GetLinkUrl` function inside a click handler for the button. Then run `Response.Redirect('yourURL')` to execute the link.

**EDIT**: As Adrian said above, a LinkButton will be the best of both worlds - it is styled like a Hyperlink, but you can set a click handler for it to get the URL dynamically, **only** when the button is actually clicked.

Comment: @Yalda, you have effectively changed the question you were asking now; the answers now make no sense, and fewer people will see your 'new' question. You may find more benefit in reverting it, then asking a new question specific to the part you're still having an issue with.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is potentially quite complex; you would need to output back to the client something indicating a call to a code-behind method to be executed before the navigation occurs, for example:

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "doClientsideCode();");
...
```

Then, a bit of JavaScript:

```
function doClientsideCode() {
    // Do a call to a service or similar, to run the method you're wanting to run.
    // This will then do the navigation you require.
}
```

Thus, my suggestion would actually be a `LinkButton`; this will fire an event that you can capture server-side, via something similar to:

```
public void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Run my method
    // Issue response.redirect to correct URL.
}
```

[Edit - in answer to the edited question, you have access to the properties CommandName and CommandArgument when using a LinkButton which should do what you require. However, I do feel that that part should now be a separate question.]